After deploy on vercel it doesn't show my website images
After deploy on Vercel it doesn't show images, I use a simple node.js server, with express
My file structure: Public/static/images/xyz.ext It must to show images in website
It must show images, it is a static simple website

Before asking question, it may be beneficial to take the tour and read the various pages in the help center, particularly How to Ask. Can you share a reproductible exemple?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
